# Error while reading RSS content using DOM

Tags: php, rss

I am using PHP XML DOM to read the content of RSS Feed. It works fine in my local server, but the hosting server it gives error like below

**`Warning: DOMDocument::load() [(B)domdocument.load]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in ....`**

After searching for that issue I found that the hosting server normally disabled that feature file_access.
What is the alternate method to read RSS content without changing the server configuration.

Here is my code snippet.

```
function readRSS ($rssURL, $entryno)
{
    //$xml ="http://feeds.feedburner.com/OnlyMyHealth-Diabetes";
     $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
     $xmlDoc->load($rssURL);
}
```

Comment: Do you have ssh acces to this hosting server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cURL, which is very powerful, and will probably be enabled (altho you can always test on your host)

One tutorial here:
http://ditio.net/2008/06/19/using-php-curl-to-read-rss-feed-xml/

But basically you do something similar to your `DOMDocument()` approach but with cURL.

**UPDATE**

You could also just cURL the RSS feed to a local folder, and use DOMDocument on the local file as it sounds like its only URL disabled (remote files).  Local might work just fine.

Comment: I like the approach, but somehow I unable to parse it.

Comment: @Ajay, why not use cURL to GRAB the file, then use `DOMDocument` to parse the xml once its local (save to local then access, etc;)